# how can i get current location of user and render components accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation, location

I want to get user's location and change the component accordingly if I can get user location I want to show a map else I want to show a div which contains some text , I've tried [geoLocated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geolocated)

but it does not show location on chrome even though I allowed the location, in some devices(mobiles and laptop) it even does not show permission request

here is some code

```
const UserMap = ({ coords }) => {
  if (!coords) {
    return <div>no location is available</div>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>lat:{coords.latitude}</div>
      <div>lat:{coords.longitude}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default geolocated({
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
})(UserMap)
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: i added the code , it works fine on firefox , and some mobile devices but in the othe it always shows `no location available` despite their browser supports geolocation

Comment: Well, some browsers just don't support this API. I guess it is as simple as that.

Comment: i would be thankful if you tell me some package that most browsers support and does this job

Comment: Check out this article: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-geolocation-call-in-reactjs. Probably it should work, since geolocation is well supported https://caniuse.com/geolocation

Comment: Important remark, geolocation works only on https for most browsers.